# A rhombus is inscribed in triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, area

> A rhombus is inscribed in triangle $ABC$ with $A$ as one of its vertices. Two sides of the rhombus lie along $AB$ and $AC$, with $AC=6, AB = 12$, and $BC = 8$. Find the length of a side of the rhombus.

So far by using heron's formula I got that the area of $ABC$ is $\sqrt {455}$, and letting $s$ be the side length of the rhombus, that $s<6$ (naturally). Also, letting the vertice of rhombus on $AB$ be $P$ and the vertice of rhombus on $AC$ be $Q$, $BP=12-s$ and $QC = 6-s$. However, I'm not sure how to carry on from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is the fourth point of the rhombus situated on $$BC$$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a vertex of the rhombus on the side $BC$.

Then, since $PR$ is parallel to $AC$, we see that $\triangle{BPR}$ and $\triangle{BAC}$ are similar.

So, we have
$$BP:BA=PR:AC\implies 12-s:12=s:6\implies s=4$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the well known formula of angle bisector at $A$ and equate it to projecton of rhombus sides on bisector. ( A result obtined by similar triangles)

$$ 2 b c/(b+c)  \cos A/2 = 2 s \cos A/2 $$
 $$ b c /(b+c) = s $$
 $$ s = \dfrac{72}{18} =4 $$

General formula is

$$ \frac{1}{s}= \frac{1}{b}+ \frac{1}{c} $$

NOTE: No need to specify  length of $BC=a\,!$

Answer (score 0):

Let $AQNP$ be our rhombus ($Q\in AC$, $P\in AB$ and $N\in BC$) and $AQ=s$.

Thus, $AN$ is a bisector of $\Delta ABC$, which says:
$$\frac{6}{12}=\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{CN}{NB}=\frac{CN}{BC-CN}=\frac{1}{\frac{BC}{CN}-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{12}{s}-1},$$
which gives $$\frac{12}{s}-1=2$$ or
$$s=4.$$